# What if you don't specify the datatype of new column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sqldatatypes

What if you don't specify the datatype of new column

```
ALTER TABLE celebs 
ADD COLUMN twitter_handle TEXT;  #what if we don't specify it's datatype TEXT?

SELECT * FROM celebs;
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the column type to something else like int? Or are you just trying to find out what happens if there is no datatype set?

Comment: Why don't you run this alter statement yourself and just find out?  Even if it works without error (it might), it is undesirable to run such a statement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I asked a question I did not force anyone to reply

Comment: @Jerome yes exactly I want to find out what happens if no datatype is set, there is no error but I wonder if you can insert all sorts of data into it this way

Comment: I mean, I would expect it to error out, but you should just try this on your version of SQLite to see what really happens.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Assuming that the sqlite tag is correct, it should not "error out".  But it is not immediately obvious as to what the sqlite type affinity would be without reading documenation, so simply running it would not reveal the details other than it would not result in an error.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for clarifying this, +1 to your answer.

Comment: @Thesnake123  You can actually insert any type of data into any sqlite column, regardless of the type of the column.  If you read the documenation, you'll discover that sqlite does not have strict types, rather a type affinity which dictates how certain values will be interpreted, stored and compared.

Comment: For essentially every other DBMS this would simply result in an error

Comment: I see thanks for clarifying, so it's a sqllite unique feature that doesn't result in any eror. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @Thesnake123: I wouldn't call the lack of proper data type checking "a feature" to be honest.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well each to it's own, I read other RDBMS have more advanced features, but I guess once in a while you just need something efficient and quick. hence the word "lite"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sqlite, the type is not required.  If no type is specified, the default type affinity will be BLOB.  See [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) for more detail including a table of examples.

Comment: there is a caveat: if the table in SQLite was created with the STRICT keyword, then every column definition must specify a datatype for that column. The freedom to specify a column without a datatype is removed. See https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html

Comment: Per the documentation: 'If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if **no type is specified** then the column has affinity BLOB.'

So the default type affinity would be **BLOB**, which actually makes sense. "NUMERIC" is only chosen as fallback when all other conditions fail.

Comment: @FilipeArruda  Thank you for pointing out my mistake.  I updated my answer to match the documentation.  The documentation has a strange way to indicate the "no type specified" default affinity--I expected it to be listed at the end of the list.